# NodeJS - Add external module via code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im having a nodeJS &express application which you can use like following:

```
var myNodeApp = require('myNodeApp');
```

my question is if there is a way to add to this application a new module/file by code

something like

```
var myNodeApp = require('myNodeApp');
myNodeApp.addModule("newModule")
```

or something like

```
myNodeApp.addFile("/path to the file")
```

That in run-time I will be able to read the content.

Im **not** talking about the typical import export(or npm install) module inside my node project(this is obvious) , I want that by code the developer(which use my node app) will be able to add file/module to my code which In RT I will be able to use.

Is it possible in node.js ?

I try to find referance about this topic without success...

Comment: [eval?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eval)

Comment: @Max - can you please elborate?

Comment: Open the link. You can use eval witch evaluate node require() module content directly.

Comment: @Max - maybe this can help :)Can you please provide an example how should I use it in my context?for example if you add some file/module with method which I want to call (inside my node app during RT)how should I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Is not clear what you want to achieve. If you want to simply include external module at run-time, is much easier to read file/string/json and loop through this list and execute the require: `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) require(myList[i]);`. With the eval you can simply add a method to your module for example: `.addModule(moduleName) { require(moduleName); }` but you loose the return from require. With eval you can do: .addModule(modName) { eval("var " +modName + " = require('" + modName + "');");}`. Beware of eval context, personally I not like eval.